# פ in German Sta"M Script

Tags: minhag, ashkenazi, aleph-bet-letters, safrus, yekke

Does anyone know the German custom for the letter pey in Sta"m sofer? I know that the shape in Litvisch Bet Yosef is influenced by the Mekubalim of Tzfat (The Ari in particular) who said that the letter bet should appear within the pey. As the Germans were quite averse to most anything kabbalistic, would this apply to a sefer written by someone who follows German minhagim?

Comment: Have you tried asking at http://www.kayj.net/?

Comment: I would, but I am unsure of how to create an account on it, as I have noticed no link.

Comment: Contact Us:E-mail: info@kayj.net Phone: +972-2-571-5824

Comment: Mistakenly identified the sefer in my answer below as "from austria". As I said in my comments to that answer, experts have identified it as "Southeast German or Czech"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the picture from my sefer, which experts have identified as either German or Czech. As you can see, there is a beis visible inside the Peh but it made neither in the style of the old European Bet Yosef ksav nor the Mishna Berurah's modification.[image: Peh, על כפו Yekke sefer torah]

Comment: How close is this to Rhineland Sta"M?

Comment: Not having a Rhineland sefer to compare it to, I can't answer that definitively but I would imagine very close.

Comment: Good point, although I know that the cultures of Hamburg and Frankfurt were worlds apart, hence the speculativeness.

Comment: Cultures were worlds apart in more recent years but STA"M tends to be very conservative by its nature

Comment: I meant more that Hamburg was ritualistically Polish, rather than Rheinisch.

Comment: could you please get me images of the parshiot of tefillin as well as the first perek of Shemot from this Torah?

Comment: Unfortunately this Torah is only a partial one. It begins in sefer vayikra (tazria, IIRC). I can only get you pictures of the last two parshiot of tefillin. How should I get them to you?

Comment: Is there a PM service? I would say my email, but I don't really want the whole internet to see it. Facebook also works.

Comment: Could you post the parshiot of שמע and והיה in a chat-room along with the section with the nun-hafucha (ויהי בנסע)

Comment: Please post here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16748/safrut-share

Comment: OK, I *finally* got them for you :)  
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17635/safrut-share

Comment: Todah rabbah (15)

Comment: were you looking for the stumos?

Comment: Not quite, I really wanted the ktav. I hope to commission a sofer to write new parshiot for me and I wanted to be as close to my ancestral minhag as possible. Also, how did you get "v'haya ki yavicha"? I thought that was in Sh'mot.