# Western Ashkenaz Mishnah Berurah

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, ashkenazi, yekke

The Mishnah Berurah was composed with the minhagim of the Eastern Ashkenazi kehillot in mind. Is there an equivalent for the communities of Western Europe*?

*The Ashkenazi communities of the Rheinland, the rest of Germany and France, England, the Netherlands, and Italy.

Comment: Can you source your first sentence?

Comment: The kizur shulchan aruch was written by an Hungarian ashkenaz rabbi. This should be close to the German minhagim

Comment: @DoubleAA, the Chofetz Chaim was a Litvak in terms of his minhagim and his hashkafah. I should think the author would qualify as a valid source.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt People can account for other perspectives than there own.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang, the Hungarians were much more machmir than the Western European Jews. I have heard that in the time of R' Hirsch, it was relatively common for the observant able balei batim to go the opera and the theatre and it was not unheard of for a rav to study non-Jewish philosophy. (Source: my grandfather grew up in Frankfurt before the war.)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Showing a kula on a derabanan (kol isha) does not demonstrate a full geography based pattern.

Comment: @DoubleAA, very true, however the Mishnah Berurah is written in a completely different context than that of Western European Jewry. Having learned his "Kuntres haOtiot" in hilchot sta"m, I can say that it does not account for alternative perspectives. See my question on the letter פ in German sta"m: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35240/פ-in-german-stam-script

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I didn't say he accounts for every alternate perspective, but your citing one instance of difference is not particularly convincing.

Comment: There is the kitsur Shulcha n Aruch of Rabbi Ernest Weil in French.

Comment: https://www.amazon.fr/Choulhane-aroukh-abr%C3%A9g%C3%A9-nouvelle-additif/dp/B008UU8NAG#immersive-view_1581794038661

Comment: @kouty, ça ne m'aide pas, parce que je comprends l'ébreu et je sais que c'était populaire aussi à Frankfort

Comment: He was a great gain. And some people say me that his book was better than the kitsur from Rabbi Shlomo Ganzfreed

Comment: The Magen Avraham

Comment: I heard from my rav that the mishna brura argued on the prevailing minhag many times. Ex. Women obligated in davening, mayim achronim...

Answer (score 1):

How's about Shorshei Minhag Ashkenaz by Rav Binyomin Hamburger (Bnei Brak) from Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz? Additionally, on their website, they have a Luach HaMinhagim for the year. I recommend checking that out as well.

Comment: I frequently use resources from MMA, although I wouldn't compare שרשי מנהג אשכנז to a משנה ברורה type sefer. The former is an exhaustive (thus-far incomplete) collection with a unique arrangement, whereas the latter follows the simanim of Shulchan 'Aruch O"C for his commentary

Comment: Did you try the Luach? Accessible here:https://www.moreshesashkenaz.org/mm/publications/MadrichEnglish.pdf